# Does iptables has pid ..?

Tags: linux, process, iptables, services, nagios

I'm using pid number to monitor uptime of all critical services. But I'm unable to find pid for iptables. Does iptables have pid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iptables` is a kernel module, not a process. you can use `lsmod` to see the various parts if they are compiled as loadable modules for your kernel

`lsmod | grep tabl`

Answer (score 3):

No, `iptables` is managed by the kernel; there is no corresponding process, so no process identifier.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to check uptime of iptables ?

Comment: Since it’s managed by the kernel, its uptime is the kernel’s.